# Best way to convert list of dates to DateFrom/DateTo range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of prices per item per day. Here's an example of how the data is stored:

```
Date       | Item  | Price
--------------------------
2020-01-01 | Item1 | 5.0
2020-01-02 | Item1 | 5.0
2020-01-03 | Item1 | 5.0
2020-01-04 | Item1 | 6.0
2020-01-05 | Item1 | 6.0
2020-01-06 | Item1 | 7.0
2020-01-07 | Item1 | 9.0
2020-01-08 | Item1 | 5.0
2020-01-09 | Item1 | 5.0
```

I want to "compress" the table by grouping the data together by item and finding the minimum and maximum date when the price was valid.

The result for the example above should be the following:

```
DateFrom   | DateTo     | Item  | Price
----------------------------------------
2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 | Item1 | 5.0
2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 | Item1 | 6.0
2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06 | Item1 | 7.0
2020-01-07 | 2020-01-07 | Item1 | 9.0
2020-01-08 | 2020-01-09 | Item1 | 5.0
```

How to achieve that in T-SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  The key observation here is that subtracting an enumerated series from the date is constant -- when the values are the same on adjacent dates:

```
select min(date), max(date), item, price
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item, price order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by item, price,
         dateadd(day, -seqnum, date);
```

Note that this formulation assumes that you have exactly one date on each day (for each item, I suppose).  If that is not the case, then ask a *new* question.  A different approach would be needed -- and the best approach depends on the exact nature of the problem.

Comment: perfect. what an elegant solution! thank you!